# .NET MVC - Nested Objects are being duplicated when Parent Object is saved again

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have an Object, that has 3 different related/nested Objects within. I am able to edit them all via a form.
What I am trying to do now, is that when I go back to Edit the Object, I want to be able to also edit those Child-Objects - Which works quite well. Except, that when I try to save it - the Child Objects are just being duplicated.

So for an example, I have the following EditorTemplate for one of the Child Objects:

```
@model Vineyard.Core.Entities.UsedIngredient

<div class="usedIngredient form-inline">
@if (Model.UsedIngredientId != 0)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(u => u.UsedIngredientId)
}
@if (Model.RecipeId != 0)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(u => u.RecipeId)
}
@Html.LabelFor(r => r.Amount)
@Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.Amount)
@Html.LabelFor(r => r.IngredientName, "Name")
@Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.IngredientName)
@Html.HiddenFor(r => r.Delete, new {@class = "mark-for-delete"})
@Html.LinkToRemoveNestedForm("Remove", "div.usedIngredient", "input.mark-for-delete")
</div>
```

I am saving the Entity like this to the DB:

```
if (recipe.RecipeId == 0)
{
  context.Recipes.Add(recipe);
}
else
{
    Recipe dbObj = context.Recipes.Find(recipe.RecipeId);
    dbObj.Name = recipe.Name;
    dbObj.Subtitle = recipe.Subtitle;
    dbObj.Instructions = recipe.Instructions;
    dbObj.Serving = recipe.Serving;
    dbObj.PrepTime = recipe.PrepTime;
    dbObj.CookingTime = recipe.CookingTime;
    dbObj.RecipeImages = recipe.RecipeImages;
    dbObj.UsedIngredients = recipe.UsedIngredients;
    dbObj.Pairings = recipe.Pairings;
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

What would prevent my Child Objects to be duplicated?

Answer (score 0):

Your child objects are fetched by another instance of the `DbContext` so Entity Framework can't track them and it doesn't know the entities already exist.

What you can do is fill in the foreign key on the `Recipe` object in stead of the navigation property:

```
dbObj.CookingTimeId = recipe.CookingTimeId
```